# Decompiled APK file manager

Tags: android-studio, apk, android-install-apk, apktool, apk-expansion-files

I've decompiled an APK file, of which I already had the source code.
But the folder I get after compilation is different from "normal".

In the normal folder (I'm implementing on Android Studio) I have:

```
.grandle
.idea
app
build
grandle
.gitignore
build.grandle
grandle.properties
gradlew
gradlew.bat
local.properties
settigs.gradle
.iml
```

In the decompiling folder I have:

```
AppInventor
com
wildebeest
kawa
org
```

This if I try to load it directly with Android Studio does not work.

How do I get a downloadable folder from Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because on decompiling an apk, you get only the source code, and not the gradle settings, dependencies etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use decompiled source code into the Android Studio as it is not java code.